# Generate IV and key using CryptoJs

Tags: key, cryptojs, passphrase

I'm using CryptoJS on a small project. For a time I used simple encryption methods. By passing a passphrase, and letting crypto-js produce the IV and KEY. This used to work very well.
Now i want to use progressive cyphering. To do this i need to explicitly provide IV and KEY.
I'm wondering how i can produce theses from a passphrase ?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the kind of thing PBKDF2 is for (password-based key derivation function).

Comment: So the key can not be send in along with the iv and encrypted content.
When decrypting the message, i have to generate again the key from the passphrase. And the newly generated key will correctly decrypt the message? Is that correct?


For the iv, i suppose that a randomly generated number/string would be ok.